# Teste & Score widget - results changing?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, orange

I'm new to Orange and to DM in general. I was using the Test & Score widget as shown in the Orange documentation examples and I noticed that the results shown in the Test & Score widget change every time I run the test again. **I've noticed it only for Classification Tree and Random Forest Classification**.

1) Is that normal? And why that only happens to those two algoritms?

2) I'm trying to compare algoritms for predicting classes in some data set. How am I supposed to compare if the results for Classifation Tree and Random Forest changes everytime I run it again?

If someone could explain that to me I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using

- random splits for evaluation, or
- randomized algorithms such as random forests

Then results change randomly unless you use a **fixed random seed**.

Comment: I'm using Classification Tree and Random Forest Classification algorithms. I'm not using random splits. I've tryied using "test on train data validation" and still got different results each run. Maybe thats supposed to happen in Random Forest but also in Classification Tree?? Is Classification Tree also random? Thank you very much.